# Matrix SDK iOS public room

Tags: swift, xcode, matrix

how I get public room in swift4.X and above using [Matrix SDK for ios](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk)

this line  **mxSession.start { response in**     //**give error -->**  `**Cannot invoke 'start' with an argument list of type '(@escaping (MXResponse<Void>) -> Void)'**`

```
let credentials = MXCredentials(homeServer: "http://matrix.org",
                                userId: "@your_user_id:matrix.org",
                                accessToken: "your_access_token")

// Create a matrix client
let mxRestClient = MXRestClient(credentials: credentials, unrecognizedCertificateHandler: nil)

// Create a matrix session
let mxSession = MXSession(matrixRestClient: mxRestClient)

// Launch mxSession: it will first make an initial sync with the homeserver
mxSession.start { response in
    guard response.isSuccess else { return }

    // mxSession is ready to be used
    // now wer can get all rooms with:
    mxSession.rooms
}
```

Comment: already tag swift4

Comment: I'm puzzled - you wrote _in swift4.X_, but your sample code is in Objective-C. @JoakimDanielson did remove `swift4` tag, but I think you should update your question & tags to make clear what you really want. And if it's really Swift 4 you're aiming at, update your question with a Swift code you have.

Comment: thanks for point it out , I have modified it also check the link of matrix

Answer (score 2):

`SwiftMatrixSDK` requires Swift 5.0. Check the [SwiftMatrixSDK.podspec](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/blob/develop/SwiftMatrixSDK.podspec#L20):

> `s.swift_version = '5.0'`

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/issues/457#issuecomment-369848753) ...

> This swift layer was brought by the community. The matrix core team runs projects in Obj-C so that maintaining this pod is not in our priorities at the moment.

... I wouldn't expect that they will be maintaining Swift 4 compatibility as well since the Swift 5 is with us for more than one year. But I can't speak for them, it's just my assumption.

---

Your example is clearly a copy & paste from the README and it doesn't work even with Swift 5. The `MXSession` initializer is fallible and you have to use:

- `guard` for the `let mxSession` or
- `mxSession?.start`, `mxSession?.rooms`

The following code compiles fine with Swift 5:

```swift
import SwiftMatrixSDK

func doSomethingWithRooms() {
    let credentials = MXCredentials(homeServer: "http://matrix.org",
                                    userId: "@your_user_id:matrix.org",
                                    accessToken: "your_access_token")

    // Create a matrix client
    let mxRestClient = MXRestClient(credentials: credentials, unrecognizedCertificateHandler: nil)

    // Create a matrix session
    guard let mxSession = MXSession(matrixRestClient: mxRestClient) else { return }

    // Launch mxSession: it will first make an initial sync with the homeserver
    mxSession.start { response in
        guard response.isSuccess else { return }

        // mxSession is ready to be used
        // now wer can get all rooms with:
        let rooms = mxSession.rooms
    }
}
```

I would say that you should [fill an issue](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/issues) (question) and ask there or switch to Swift 5.

---

The project migrated to Swift 5 in the `v0.13.0` version. Check the [release notes](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.13.0):

> SwiftMatrixSDK: Migrate to Swift 5.0.

Theoretically, the previous version ([v0.12.5](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.12.5)) should work with Swift 4. Should work means that you should be able to compile it, but it will lack quite a lot of features and bug fixes, because this version was released on May 3, 2019.

Comment: hi thanks for the response buddy, any work around solution to work it with swift4.x and Xcode 11.3 and above ? As native integration of API sucks

Comment: It seems that they migrated to Swift 5 in the [v0.13.0](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.13.0) version (SwiftMatrixSDK: Migrate to Swift 5.0.). Try to use v0.12.5 version.

Comment: I also put https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk/issues/878 but no answer yet

Comment: I am able to compile it with swift4.x but those methods are not working for fencing room details etc

Comment: Expected, because it's quite an old version and it lacks lot of new features, ... You said that you're using Xcode 11.3 which includes Swift 5.1.3. Why Swift 4 then? Why Xcode 11.3 and not 11.6? You can mix and match Swift 4 & Swift 5 in your project.

Comment: just rectified I check in Xcode Version 11.5 , its compile but no method works.
And Native API are so much work to do. My bad luck

Comment: how to get chat of the room as MXstore not working and how do I get chat from it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you someone explain me how to make upload and download mediaFiles with this SDK.
Ok i read documentation but i don't understand a lot of it.
I make seasion in room and what to do next, where and how to make upload with userA and download from userB.
I wrote Swift 5

Comment: did you able to fetch rooms ?

Comment: Yes @9to5ios  , i make a MXFileStore start the session and fetch rooms. How can i now send some type of file ?

Comment: Access the default code gives me error ====>Cannot invoke 'start' with an argument list of type '(@escaping (MXResponse<Void>) -> Void)'

Comment: can you able to load all messages with history ?